# Difference between sockaddr and sockaddr_storage

Tags: c, sockets

Which are the difference between sockaddr and sockaddr_storage? I don't understand because looking at the code they look quite the same:

```
struct sockaddr {
    uint8_t sa_len;
    sa_family_t sa_family;
    char sa_data[14];
}

struct sockaddr_storage {
    uint8_t ss_len;
    sa_family_t ss_family;
    char ss_padding[SIZE];
}
```

Answer (score 17):

The `storage` variant is meant to be "as big as the maximum possible size", and properly aligned too (so it can hold an IPv6 address, or an IPv4 address, or an ISO protocol address, or even an `AF_UNIX` pathname or whatever).  Think of it as a bin/barrel/breadbox/(other favorite storage item) that's big enough to hold "any socket address", no matter what kind of socket address it is.  An IPv4 address (`struct sockaddr_in`) is tiny and clearly can't hold an IPv6 address within it, but a `struct sockaddr_storage` has a large roomy cargo area.

The original `struct sockaddr` probably *should* have been this big, but wasn't.  So this is basically a workaround for a historical error.

(The version you quoted above does not have an alignment item in it, which seems suspect.)

Comment: [RFC-2553](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2553.txt), [RFC-3493](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3493.txt) §3.10 - Portability Additions.

Comment: But if a `struct sockaddr` can contain a `struct sockaddr_in6` why do I need a `struct sockaddr_storage`?

Comment: It can't (contain a `sockaddr_in6`).  The old `sockaddr` is 16 bytes and a `struct sockaddr_in6` is 32 bytes.  The `storage` version is 128 bytes long, on the systems I've seen/used.

Comment: @torek But all socket functions I know want a pointer to a `sockaddr` as argument - not a `sockaddr_storage*`?

Comment: @DarthMoon: Yes. It's somewhat of a historical mistake: they probably should take `void *`. If you're using an inet (not inet6) connection you need the actual address of an actual `sockaddr_in`. If you're using an inet6 connection you need the actual address of an actual `sockadder_in6`. If you're using a unix-domain connection, you need the actual address of an actual `sockaddr_un`. If you're writing a library that needs to provide *space for* someone else to *shove in* any of these, you need to provide an actual sockaddr_storage.

Comment: Except that `sockaddr_storage` might not fit `sockaddr_un` on all platforms :) https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/bits/socket.h;h=a011a8c0959b9970f9784f431713a17b4ef7c682;hb=HEAD#l185
*Structure large enough to hold any socket address (with the historical exception of AF_UNIX).*

Comment: @domen: `SS_SIZE` *should* be defined here to be big enough to hold a `sockaddr_un` as well. The comment is, I think, meant to imply that they aren't sure that it *is*. But it's *supposed to be*. (Of course the real mistake here is this fixed size in the first place.)

Answer (score 2):

Originally in sockets programming there was a `SOCKADDR` *(socket address)*—protocol agnostic blob that represented *"an address"*. It could be an IPX address, an IPv4 address, an AppleTalk address, whatever.

```
SOCKADDR (16-bytes)      SOCKADDR_IN (16-bytes)     
(Protocol agnostic)      (SOCKADDR for IPv4)        
+---------------------+  +-----------------------+  
| sa_family (2-bytes) |  | sin_family (2-bytes)  |  
|---------------------|  |-----------------------|  
| sa_data (14-bytes)  |  | sin_port (2-bytes)    |  
|                     |  | S_addr (4-bytes)      |  
|                     |  |                       |  
|                     |  | sin_zero (8-bytes)    |  
|                     |  |                       |  
|                     |  |                       |  
|                     |  |                       |  
+---------------------+  +-----------------------+
```

The original hope was that the 16-byte `SOCKADDR` structure would be large enough to handle any protocol there is, or ever will be. This meant that `SOCKADDR` would be protocol agnostic.

## But IPv6

But then IPv6, with it's 16-byte (128-bit) addresses, came along. Suddenly the 14-byte payload of a `SOCKADDR` structure wasn't large enough (12-bytes once you subtract 2-bytes for the port number):

```
SOCKADDR (16-bytes)      SOCKADDR_IN (16-bytes)     SOCKADDR_IN6 (24-bytes)
(Protocol agnostic)      (SOCKADDR for IPv4)        (SOCKADDR for IPv6)
+---------------------+  +-----------------------+  +-------------------------+
| sa_family (2-bytes) |  | sin_family (2-bytes)  |  | sin6_family (2-bytes)   |
|---------------------|  |-----------------------|  |-------------------------|
| sa_data (14-bytes)  |  | sin_port (2-bytes)    |  | sin6_port (2-bytes)     |
|                     |  | S_addr (4-bytes)      |  | sin6_flowinfo (4-bytes) |
|                     |  |                       |  |                         |
|                     |  | sin_zero (8-bytes)    |  | IN6_ADDR (16 bytes)     |
|                     |  |                       |  |                         |
|                     |  |                       |  |                         |
|                     |  |                       |  |                         |
+---------------------+  +-----------------------+  |                         |
                                                    |                         |
                                                    |                         |
                                                    |                         |
                                                    +-------------------------+
```

So a **new** protocol agnostic ***SOCKET ADDRESS*** structure was created:

> <strike>SOCKADDR</strike> → SOCKADDR_STORAGE

```
SOCKADDR_STORAGE (128-bytes)  SOCKADDR_IN (16-bytes)     SOCKADDR_IN6 (24-bytes)
 (protcol agnostic)            (IPv4)                     (IPv6)
+---------------------+       +-----------------------+  +-------------------------+
| ss_family (2-bytes) |       | sin_family (2-bytes)  |  | sin6_family (2-bytes)   |
|---------------------|       |-----------------------|  |-------------------------|
| ss_pad (126-bytes)  |       | sin_port (2-bytes)    |  | sin6_port (2-bytes)     |
|                     |       | S_addr (4-bytes)      |  | sin6_flowinfo (4-bytes) |
|                     |       |                       |  |                         |
|                     |       | sin_zero (8-bytes)    |  | IN6_ADDR (16 bytes)     |
|                     |       |                       |  |                         |
|                     |       |                       |  |                         |
|                     |       |                       |  |                         |
|                     |       +-----------------------+  |                         |
|                     |                                  |                         |
|                     |                                  |                         |
|                     |                                  |                         |
|                     |                                  +-------------------------+ 
|                     | 
|                     |
|                     |
 .....................
|                     |
|                     |
|                     |
|                     |
+---------------------+
```

So the goal is to get everyone to stop using `SOCKADDR` (the failed attempt at a protocol agnostic structure),
replace all references with `SOCKADDR_STORAGE`.

So all header files ideally would be changed:

```
--- int connect(int sockfd, const struct sockaddr         *addr, socklen_t addrlen);
+++ int connect(int sockfd, const struct sockaddr_storage *addr, socklen_t addrlen);
```

And hopefully 128-bytes is enough that we never have to go through this ever again.